# How can i retrieve int data from one activity and set it to textView of another activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Sending class code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, QuizActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("name", name);
        startActivity(i);
```

Recieving class code:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent != null) {
        totalScore = intent.getIntExtra("totalScore",0);
    }
    TextView scoreView = findViewById(R.id.totalScore);
    scoreView.setText(totalScore);
```

Comment: i think parameter name is not set only name is set in intent and on receiving side code is expecting totalScore in intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the sender side, use Intent.putExtra:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
myIntent.putExtra("totalScore", intValue);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

On the receiver side, use Intent.getIntExtra:

```
 Intent mIntent = getIntent();
 int totalScore = mIntent.getIntExtra("totalScore", 0);
 TextView scoreView = findViewById(R.id.totalScore);
 scoreView.setText(totalScore+"");
```

Comment: Please debug and check whether you are passing the value. In the sending side you are passing only the name

Comment: Thanks it is resolved

Comment: Please upvote then it will be helpful for others too